# How do I make sense of the following definitions of tangent vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

I am teaching myself differential geometry in manifolds. I am reading a book, which at the beginning sets some notation that might be important for my question so I report  it here just in case it is not standard

**Some notation**

"$u^i $" is the n-th natural coordinate (projection) $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, so that $u=(u^1,...,u^n)$ is the identity function of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For a chart $(U,x)$The n functions $x^1,...,x^n: U \to \mathbb{R}$, components of $x$ given by $x^i=u^i\circ x$ are coordinate (functions) in $U$ with respect to the chart. $(x^1,...,x^n)$ is a local coordinate system and $x^1,...,x^n$ are called local coordinates, at $p$, if $p$ is a point of $U$

**Applied vectors as tangent vectors .**
Let $p$ be a point of  $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The operator $D_k|_p : f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to D_kf(p)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u^k}(p) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a tangent vector to $\mathbb{R}^n$at  $p$**...(1)**

So that to each applied vector$ (p,\nu) \in \{p\}\times \mathbb{R}^n $ it is associated a tangent vector $D_{(p,\nu)} \in T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ defined as $D_{(p,\nu)}f=(d/dt)_0 (f(p+t\nu))$ , directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ with respect to $\nu$. This can be written as $D_{(p,\nu)}f= \nu^k D_k|_pf=\nu^k D_{(p,e_k)}f$

**Tangent vectors associated to a local coordinate system**

Let $p$ be a point of the n-manifold $M$, to each chart $(U,x)$, there are $n$ tangent vectors associated at $p$. The k-th one is

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}|_p : f \in C^\infty(M) \to \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}(p)=D_k(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p))$**...(2)**

So regarding this two points my questions are:

1. I am a bit confused about the use of $x$ vs $u$. $x^i$ are coordinates but at the same time the components of the homeomorphism $x$ In (1), if the coordinates are supposed to be $x^1,...,x^n$, why is the partial derivative taken with respect to the identity function components $\frac{\partial }{\partial u^k}$?
2. Regarding (2), Is this $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}(p)=D_k(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p))$ a definition or is it something that can be proven?. If I try to do the derivative of the composition at some point I have to derivate the inverse function "$x^{-1}$", and I am getting nowhere. Where does the "$\circ x^{-1}$" even come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the point: to work on a manifold we use coordinate charts $(U,x)$ so that, in this chart, we work as in $\mathbb{R}^n$, WLOG we can assume that $x: U\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Differential geometry is constructed in a way such that partial derivatives represented by $\frac{\partial}{\partial u^k}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in $U$ under the coordinate system $x$ are denoted by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$.

That is: $x$ act as a diffeomorphism between $U\subset M$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, therefore if we have a differentiable function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$, where $M$ is a manifold, then using the coordinate system $x$ in $U$ we define

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\bigg|_p f:=\frac{\partial}{\partial u^k}\bigg|_{x(p)}(f\circ x^{-1})
$$
That is: to differentiate $f$ we do it locally using coordinate charts, we use the calculus in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to define a local calculus in $M$. This is all. We use the Euclidean spaces to model a differential calculus in what we call differentiable manifolds: sets with an structure such that locally are diffeomorphic to an Euclidean space.

ADDITION: the $\circ x^{-1}$ is needed because we are transporting $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we do it using the diffeomorphism $x$. Note that the domain of $f$ is $M$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: "partial derivatives represented by $\frac{\partial}{\partial u^k}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in $U$ under the coordinate system $x$ are denoted by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$." Actually I would say it is the other way around, in calculus I am used to do $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$. The use of the identity function componets $u^i$ in place of the coodinates $x^i$ which I am not familiar with is what is confusing me, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO you mean the notation? If you are used to a different notation then use it, but there $x$ is the chart so you cannot use $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ to represent partial derivatives in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you will need to change the notation for the coordinate function. By example, instead of naming it $x$ we can call it $\varphi $ so you can represent the derivations in $U$ by $\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi ^k}$. However $x$ is not used as the identity function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in any book of differential geometry that I've read. This is because in general you ...

Comment: (continuation) ... represent all in $M$, not in $\mathbb{R}^n$. There $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the underlying model but its not usually used when working on $M$. I added the explanation for $\circ x^{-1}$

Comment: I mean in standard calculus the partial derivatives are represented as $\frac{\partial  }{\partial x^i}$ where $ x^i $are just independ variables and never with respect to functions , as you are writing $\frac{\partial  }{\partial\varphi ^i}$ or as in the book $\frac{\partial  }{\partial u^i}$ Should I see the components of the homeomorphism as independent variables in $U$ to make sense of $\frac{\partial  }{\partial\varphi ^i}$ ?. Furthermore the only "name " for the identity function I have seen is "id"

Comment: @J.C.VegaO you can see them as independent variables if you wish. Yes, its confusing I know, the $\varphi ^k$ represent coordinates of points in $U$, this is because $\varphi :U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is bijective, so to symbolically represent points in $U$ under the coordinate system $\varphi $ we use these symbols because for every $q\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $\varphi^{-1} (q)$ is a point in $U$. This is way the symbol $x$ is usually chosen to represent the coordinate system, so it represent points in $U$ also

Comment: Regarding (2), So you say (2) is a definition? I wonder if I can see if I can see it as something proven instead, Would the following make sense as a "proof" ?

Let $h= f\circ x^{-1}$ and $f= f\circ x^{-1}\circ x=h \circ x$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}|_p =\frac{\partial (h\circ x)}{\partial x^k}(p)=D_kh|_{x(p)}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^k}|_p=D_kh|_{x(p)}.1=D_k f\circ x^{-1}|_{x(p)}=D_k (f\circ x^{-1})(x(p))$

Comment: I still should establish carefully the domains, though

Comment: @J.C.VegaO (2) is a definition, it cannot be proved. We define calculus on abstract (differentiable) manifolds transporting everything to an Euclidean space.

Comment: I meant only the identity "$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}(p)=D_k(f \circ x^{-1})(x(p))$", or also this part is to be taken as definition and my proof makes no sense?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO this identity is a definition, its the definition of the symbol $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$

Comment: Can't I regard that symbol as a standard partial derivative (defined with the well-known limit)?